# Applying `.font` and other styles to Swift Charts legend

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using Swift Charts in macOS 13 (iOS 16), to adjust the text font in a Chart's Axis, you create an AxisMarks that includes AxisValueLabel, and attach it there. For example:

```
    Chart() { ... }
    .chartXAxis {
        AxisMarks() {
            AxisValueLabel().font(.title)
        }
```

How can you do the same thing for `.chartLegend`, keeping the auto-generated legend, but adjusting its font?